# How to remove many to many from a queryset in Django

Tags: django, many-to-many, bulkupdate

I have a queryset

```
Class SmallFoo(Model):
     text = models.CharField()

Class Foo(Model):
     small_foo = models.ManyToManyField(SmallFoo)
```

e.g.`Foo.objects.filter(id__in=[2,4,6]).update(small_foo__remove=[1,2])`

I want to do something like above i.e. for a query-set update the manytomany field for all of them. Is it possible to do that? 
I do not want to iterate over each object in queryset and fire separate queries for them. (It takes too much time)

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it helps your but you can try this

```
[f.small_foo.all().update(text="test") for f in Foo.objects.all()]
```

you still have to iterate over Foo but update all related SmallFoo at same time

Comment: Unfortunately I want to avoid doing the above. As I have 5000 Foo objects and iterating over them takes a few seconds and I want to avoid that.